# The best way to sync ActiveRecord structure between rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, distributed-system

I am developing a distributed system consisting of rails apps. There are multiple servers in different geographical locations producing some data that should be synced with a single cloud server and then distributed among the "local" servers. In other words, there is a shared state stored on the "global" server and partially on the "local" ones and its changes are lazily actualized by the "local" servers.

ActiveRecord models to be synced have the same definition both on the "local" servers and the "global" one. But they are maintained separately just by a developers convention. Thus there might some synchronization issues including differences in model definitions.

What is the best way to share the model definitions between the servers and implement their validation?

The solution I've come up with is to move model definitions into a separate versioned library (gem), share it between servers and use serialization and deserialization (`as_json` and `from_json` methods) to ensure that the structure of the model received by the cloud server is correct while syncing.

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing it?

Comment: I don't think there's an "idiomatic" way of doing this, simply because people don't do this often enough. Every such situation is a unique snowflake.

Comment: Your solution is one valid possibility. If you choose this one then you should consider using uuid's as primary keys or another uniq id mechanism between all servers. I would consider creating an API instead of sharing the DB. An API can be stable between all apps and does not rely on the persistence layer.